# When and where to use abstract classes and when and where to use interfaces in Java?

Tags: java, interface, abstract-class

Abstract classes and interfaces play very a important role in Java and they have their own importance in certain situations. They possess certain special characteristics. There are some observable differences between them. Let me describe some a few of them.

---

One of the major differences between an interface and an abstract class is that an abstract class can never be instantiated, an interface however can.

Both of them can never be declared as final obviously, because they are to be inherited by some other non-abstract class(es).

Both of them can never have static methods. Neither concrete nor abstract (abstract static methods indeed and in fact, don't exist at all).

An interface can never never have concrete methods (a method with it's actual implementation), an abstract class however can have concrete methods too.

An interface can not have constructors, an abstract class can however can have.

---

Two obvious questions are likely to arise here.

An abstract class can never be instantiated  because it is by nature, not a fully implemented class and it's full implementation requires it to be inherited by some other non-abstract class(es). If it is so then, an abstract class should not have a constructor of it's own because a constructor implicitly returns an object of it's own class and an abstract class by itself can not be instantiated hence, it should not be able to have a constructor of it's own.

An interface somewhat looks better and more appropriate to use than an abstract class, since it imposes less restrictions than what those are imposed by an abstract class. In which **very specific situations**, an interface is useful and in which **very specific situations**, an abstract class is appropriate? Hope! the boldface letters would be taken into much consideration.

Comment: That part about constructors sounds wrong to me.

Comment: An interface cannot be instantiated. A class that implements an interface can be (if it's not abstrace).

Comment: Several of your "observations" are more imaginations I fear. You can't instantiate interfaces and you CAN have static methods in abstract classes

Comment: Actually, you might want to implement constructors in an abstract class if you want to force common creational behaviour in extending classes. On another note, an interface per se can't be instantiated, you can only have instances of implementing classes.

Comment: Rather than putting down answers to your own question, it would be better to edit your question and remove the incorrect statements.  Leave the answers up to others when you are asking questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, you're factually wrong in a few places:

- One of the major differences between an interface and an abstract class is that an abstract class can never be instantiated, an interface however can.

#### Wrong. An abstract and interface can both be instantiated anonymously.

- Both of them can never be declared as final obviously, because they are to be inherited by some other non-abstract class(es).

#### True, although I personally see no reason why interfaces couldn't have been able to be final so they couldn't be extended, but that's just me. I see why they made the decision they did.

- Both of them can never have static methods. Neither concrete nor abstract (abstract static methods indeed and in fact, don't exist at all).

#### Abstract classes can have static methods; sorry!

- An interface can never never have concrete methods (a method with it's actual implementation), an abstract class however can have concrete methods too.

#### Yes, that's one of the the primary differences between them.

- An interface can not have constructors, an abstract class can however can have.

#### Yes, that's true.

Now, let's move on to your questions:

Your first paragraph doesn't have a question in it. What was the question there? If it was "Why allow abstract classes to have constructors if you can't instantiate them?" the answer is so child classes can use it. Here's an example

```
abstract class Parent {
    String name;
    int id;
    public Parent(String n, int i) { name = n; id = i; }
}

class Child extends Parent {
    float foo;
    public Child(String n, int i, float f) {
        super(n,i);
        foo = f;
    }
}

// later
Parent p = new Parent("bob",12); // error
Child c = new Child("bob",12); // fine!
```

Your second paragraph has a question but is malformed. I think you're simply missing an 'is' in there... :) The answer to it is as follows:

You use an interface when you want to define a contract. Here's a very specific example:

```
public interface Set<E> {
    int size(); // determine size of the set
    boolean isEmpty(); // determine if the set is empty or not
    void add(E data); // add to the set
    boolean remove(E data); // remove from the set
    boolean contains(E data); // determine if set holds something
}
```

Four common methods to all sets.

You use an abstract class when you want to define SOME of the behavior, but still have the contract

```
public abstract class AbstractSet<E> implements Set<E> {
   // we define the implementation for isEmpty by saying it means
   // size is 0
   public boolean isEmpty() { return this.size() == 0; }
   // let all the other methods be determined by the implementer
}
```

Comment: Neither an interface nor an abstract class can be instantiated, "instantiating them anonymously" is really instantiating an anonymous class which extends the abstract class or implements the interface.

Comment: @Daniel I agree with your assessment. The point I was trying to make is that the difference he was trying to make isn't there. It would be safe to say that they aren't instantiated, there's just syntactic sugar around doing it anonymously, or on the flip side you could say what I said up there. But it would not be correct to say that one can be instantiated and the other couldn't. If your definition allows for one, it allows for the other too. If it disallows one, it disallows the other. That was the distinction I was attempting to make; your assessment is spot on.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time, when the discussion comes up between deciding if you should use interfaces or abstract classes, it ends up with definitions of how to use them, but not always why and when?  Also the obvious other concrete classes and utility classes that you may end up using as well aren't always brought up.  Really, in my thinking the correct way to answer the question is to determine the context you are dealing with regarding the domain or entity objects, namely what is your use case?

From a very high level, Java consists of objects (entities or domain objects that can model objects in the real world) that communicate with each other using methods. In any event, you want to model behavior with interfaces and use abstract classes when you have inheritance.

In my personal experience, I do this using a top down and then bottom up approach.  I start looking for inheritance by looking at the use case and seeing what classes I will need.  Then I look to see if there is a superClassOrInterfaceType (since both classes and interfaces define types, I'm combining them into a one word for simplicity. Hopefully it doesn't make it more confusing) domain object that would encompass all the objects, as in a superClassOrInterfaceType of vehicle if I'm working on a use case dealing with subtypeClassOrInterfaceTypes like: cars, trucks, jeeps, and motorcycles for example.  If there is a hierarchy relationship, then I define the superClassOrInterfaceType and subtypeClassOrInterfaceTypes.

As I said, what I generally do first is to look for a common domain superClassOrInterfaceType for the objects I'm dealing with. If so, I look for common method operations between the subtypeClassOrInterfaceTypes.  If not, I look to see if there are common method implementations, because even though you may have a superClassOrInterfaceType and may have common methods, the implementations may not favor code reuse.  At this point, if I have common methods, but no common implementations, I lean towards an interface.  However, with this simplistic example, I should have some common methods with some common implementations between the vehicle subtypeClassOrInterfaceTypes that I can reuse code with.

On the other hand, if there is no inheritance structure, then I start from the bottom up to see if there are common methods.  If there are no common methods and no common implementations, then I opt for a concrete class.

Generally, if there is inheritance with common methods and common implementations and a need for multiple subtype implementation methods in the same subtype, then I go with an abstract class, which is rare, but I do use it.  If you just go with Abstract classes just because there is inheritance, you can run into problems if the code changes a lot.  This is detailed very well in the example here: [Interfaces vs Abstract Classes in Java](http://www2.sys-con.com/itsg/virtualcd/java/archives/0604/meyer/index.html), for the different types of domain objects of motors.  One of them required a dual powered motor, that required multiple subtype implementation methods to be used in a single subtype class.

To sum it all up, as a rule you want to define behaviors (what the objects will do) with interfaces and not in Abstract classes.  Abstract classes focus on an implementation hierarchy and code reuse.

Here are some links that go into greater details on this.

[Thanks Type & Gentle Class](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2074906/core-java/thanks-type-and-gentle-class.html)

[The Magic behind Subtype Polymorphism](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2075223/core-java/reveal-the-magic-behind-subtype-polymorphism.html)

[Maximize Flexibility with Interfaces & Abstract Classes](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2075627/core-java/maximize-flexibility-with-interfaces-and-abstract-classes.html)

[Interfaces vs Abstract Classes in Java](http://www2.sys-con.com/itsg/virtualcd/java/archives/0604/meyer/index.html)